# python 3.5 console not able to type the 'c' key

Tags: macos, mac, python, iterm2, python3

I have a very strange problem when using the python3 console. Whenever I type <kbd>c</kbd> (the actual `c` character) what gets written is the `<tab>` character. So in essence I can't type anything that requires the character c. Has anyone else encountered this problem? How have you solved?

The python2.7 console behaves correctly, this is only seen in the python3 console. I'm on a macbook pro, with iTerm 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out there was a `.pythonrc` file in my user home, which was the root cause for this behavior. Changing the file fixed it.